# Directory disappears from azure cloud shell (home)

Tags: azure, cloud

## Scenario

I had a working directory (repo) on azure cloudshell (cloud shell on azure portal) at home which i don't see now.
It disappeared couple of days as well but appeared again automatically after couple of hours.

Now again it has disappeared. Not sure how to get it back.

---

I could find below on microsoft pages which says $Home gets persisted so my directory should have been persisted.

System state and persistence
The machine that provides your Cloud Shell session is temporary, and it is recycled after your session is inactive for 20 minutes. Cloud Shell requires an Azure file share to be mounted. As a result, your subscription must be able to set up storage resources to access Cloud Shell. Other considerations include:

With mounted storage, only modifications within the clouddrive directory are persisted. In Bash, your $HOME directory is also persisted.
Azure file shares can be mounted only from within your assigned region.
In Bash, run env to find your region set as ACC_LOCATION.
Azure Files supports only locally redundant storage and geo-redundant storage accounts.

---

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong ?

I could clone the my repo from azure devOps but I dont want to. This would be my last option.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the repo? Can you provide more details about how you use the cloud shell?

Comment: I used it from azure portal. I cloned my repo there. Repo is my git repository. I was referring that repo as my directory. That directory is outside of my azure clouddrive.

Comment: I mean how do you use the repo in cloud shell?

Comment: not sure if I understood that question correctly, but I login to Azure portal, then I click on icon  **>_** in top header panel on right side, which opens a terminal. There i had cloned my repo using git clone command.

Comment: It seems you store the repo files in the cloud shell home directory. And the directory is also a persist storage. So it's a strange thing that the data disappear in that directory. Maybe it's the capacity issue. Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the cloud shell and my repo appeared again. 
It would be still good to know why it disappeared :)